# jQuery: Toggle field attribute: un-checked Checkbox means disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to edit a multi-select field when ("Update Data?") Checkbox is **checked**, and `disabled` the field again, when checkbox is **un-checked**.

Important is that **checked** status always leads to being able to edit, meanwhile **un-checked** means field is `disabled`, regardless if I load the form with a **checked** box or as **un-checked** as the initial state (I can save either or)

I find several useful answers but struggling with syntax to combine those into my solution.

Below can toggle once, then it gets stuck:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    if ($("#field2").attr('disabled', !this.checked)) {
      $("#field2").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#field2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="div_id_product" class="form-group row"> <label for="field2" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">
                Multiselect
            </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <select name="multiselect" class="select2-show-search selectmultiple form-control" id="field2" disabled="disabled" multiple style="width: 100%;">
        <option value="1" selected>Product 1 </option>
        <option value="3" selected>Product 3</option>
        <option value="2">Product 2</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row" id="checkbox1"> <label for="id_to_update" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">
            Update Data?
        </label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <div class="input-group"> <input type="checkbox" name="to_update" class="checkboxinput" id="id_to_update"> <span class="input-group-append"></span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Jaco can you paste your html code also

Comment: done, please see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your JS to this. You have the `change` listener on the wrong id. 

The listener should be on `#id_to_update` (input) instead of `#checkbox1` which is the div.

```
$(function() {
    $("#id_to_update").change(function() {
        $("#field2").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution you are looking for

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field-editable').change(function() {
    $('#firstname').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <label for="field-editable">
        <input type="checkbox" id="field-editable">
        do you want to edit            
        </label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

Comment: And this is even cooler: `$('#field-editable').change(function() {
    $('#firstname').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  }).change()`